# Why does ::first-letter stop working as soon as I add display: flex or inline-flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I've implemented some `::first-letter` styles for my `p` elements. However, when I add `display: inline-flex` to make them inline, all the `::first-letter` styles stop working.

How can I make the elements inline while keeping the `::first-letter` styles?

```
 p:first-of-type::first-letter {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 p:nth-of-type(2)::first-letter {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

  p:nth-of-type(3)::first-letter {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

/* inline container */
p {                               
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: FYI: In FF this isn´t doing aything at all :)

Comment: Removing the inline-flex rule fixes the issue, but I don't know why. Why are you using inline-flex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A flex container (that is, an element with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`) cannot contain a `::first-letter` pseudo-element, since a flex container contains flex items, not formatted lines. That's why making your `p` elements flex containers disables all your `::first-letter` rules.

This appears to be the [classic case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex/27459133#27459133) of [using `display: flex`/`inline-flex` when you're not trying to create a flex layout within each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848799/purpose-making-div-inline-should-display-be-inline-flex-or-inline-block). For inline (or horizontal) layout of block containers, use `display: inline-block`, `display: table-cell`, or floats, instead.

Comment: If I use diplay: inline-block solves the problem, but then top margin disapears. https://jsfiddle.net/Lfkf1dtx/1/